# $\vert\mathbb Z\vert = \vert\mathbb N\vert$ by defining a bijection $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb N$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Question: **"Prove that $\vert\mathbb Z\vert = \vert\mathbb N\vert$ by defining a bijection $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb N$."**

I wanted to check whether this is a valid answer.

$$f(n) =
\begin{cases}
-2n-1,  & n\lt0 \\
2n, & n\geq0
\end{cases}$$

Comment: To check its validity, try checking that the function you defined is one-one and onto function. I trust you know one-one and onto.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165334/prove-the-cardinality-of-mathbbz-and-mathbbn-is-the-same Also have a look at this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use $z$ to represent an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ so that we can reserve $n$ for the natural numbers. The function you've defined becomes:

$$f(z) =
\begin{cases}
-2z-1,  & z\lt0 \\
2z, & z\geq0
\end{cases}$$

As an example, I'll demonstrate surjectivity and leave it to you to show that the function is injective. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary, if $n$ is even then $z = n/2$ satisfies $f(z) = n.$ If instead $n$ is odd, then $z = - \frac{n+1}{2}$ satisfies $f(z) = n.$ Hence, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists *at least one* $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $f(z) = n,$ so $f$ is surjective.