# What is an example of an injective map from Z to N?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Of course, $f(x)=x^2, x>0$ is injective but I don't think this is answering the question.

Comment: Hint: 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, ...

Comment: It does not answer the question because as soon as you say $x>0$ you no longer have domain $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [$\vert\mathbb Z\vert = \vert\mathbb N\vert$ by defining a bijection $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310714/vert-mathbb-z-vert-vert-mathbb-n-vert-by-defining-a-bijection-f-mathbb-z)? If you can find a *bijection*, you have found an *injection*.

Comment: I was under the impression that if a question asks for an injective map/function, then it can only be injective and not bijective - otherwise, it would simply ask for a bijective function.

Comment: If a map is injective, it could be either bijective (hence also surjective), or not bijective - i.e. only injective. In both cases the condition of being injective is satisfied, so both options work

Comment: If you *really* want to omit a natural number from the image of $f$, increase the value of the (previously bijective) function by $1$, thus avoiding the smallest natural number ($0$, or $1$ - depending how you have defined $\mathbb N$).